# curl | tar - gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

Tags: unix, curl, ffmpeg, pipe, tar

I'm trying to install ffmpeg on travis with this command:

```
curl http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz | tar -C /usr/local/bin/ -xvz
```

I get this error:

```
$ curl http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz | tar -C /usr/local/bin/ -xvz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time      Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left      Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command "curl http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz | tar -C /usr/local/bin/ -xvz" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

however, it works locally on OS X. what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like i just used the wrong command! should've been

```
curl http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz | sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin/ -xJ --strip-components=1
```

Answer (score 1):

`.xz` is not `.gz`. GNU `tar` apparently recognises XZ format; but OS X does not use GNU tools. I found [this quote](https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/archive-utility-xz.html):

> Without installing anything, a TAR archive can be created with XZ compression using the `tar` program with the undocumented `--xz` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your tar might not be able to handle `.xz` files.

According to[this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz) you can try to install `xz-utils` and use the `-J` flag:

```
tar -C /path/to/output -xJv
```